# Search partial filenames in C++ using boost filesystem

Tags: c++, search, boost, boost-filesystem

the question is simple , I want to find a file path inside a directory but I have only part of the filename, so here is a functions for this task

```
void getfiles(const fs::path& root, const string& ext, vector<fs::path>& ret)
{
    if(!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) return;

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;
    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(fs::is_regular_file(*it)&&it->path().extension()==ext) ret.push_back(it->path());//
        ++it;

    }

}

bool find_file(const filesystem::path& dir_path, const filesystem::path file_name, filesystem::path& path_found) {
    const fs::recursive_directory_iterator end;
    const auto it = find_if(fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir_path), end,
                            [file_name](fs::path e) {


            cerr<<boost::algorithm::icontains(e.filename().native() ,file_name.native())<<endl;
            return boost::algorithm::icontains(e.filename().native() ,file_name.native());//
});

    if (it == end) {
        return false;
    } else {
        path_found = it->path();
        return true;
    }
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    vector<fs::path> inputClass ;
    fs::path textFiles,datasetPath,imgpath;
    textFiles=argv[1];
    datasetPath=argv[2];

    getfiles(textFiles,".txt",inputClass);
    
    for (int i=0;i<inputClass.size();i++)
        
    {
        ifstream lblFile(inputClass[i].string().c_str());
        string line;
        fs::path classname=inputClass[i].parent_path()/inputClass[i].stem().string();
        cerr<<classname.stem()<<endl;
        while (getline(lblFile,line))
        {
            
            bool find=find_file(datasetPath,line,imgpath);
            if (find)
            {
                
                while(!fs::exists(classname))
                    fs::create_directories (classname);
                fs::copy(imgpath,classname/imgpath.filename());
                cerr<<"Found\n";
            }
            else
                cerr<<"Not Found \n";
            
            
        }
        lblFile.close();
    }
    
    
}
```

Console out:

```
"490"
vfv343434.jpeg||E9408000EC0
0
fsdfdsfdfsf.jpeg||E9408000EC0
0
1200E9408000EC0.jpeg||E9408000EC0
0
Not Found
```

but when I set the search string manually it works fine ! I tried other methods for searching string like std::find but all the methods fail to find the substring, it seems there is problem with  input string (line) I printed all the chars but no especial characters or anything.
if I set the search string manually it works as desired

```
string search="E9408000EC0";
        cerr<<e.filename().native()<<"||"<<search<<endl;
        cerr<<boost::algorithm::icontains(e.filename().native() ,search)<<endl;
```

the results for above change is like

```
"490"
vfv343434.jpeg||E9408000EC0
0
fsdfdsfdfsf.jpeg||E9408000EC0
0
1200E9408000EC0.jpeg||E9408000EC0
1
Found
```

Comment: I fail to grok 'boost' docs.  Have you a reason to avoid std::filesystem?

Comment: @2785528 how is that relevant? Do you have reason to think the Boost implementation is flawed just because you fail to grok the docs? Let's focus on the question instead.

Comment: @2785528   iI've tried std::filesystem too no luck there is a problem with my input i think I updated my questions please take a look

Comment: I honestly don't really understand the problem. Can you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this.

The only hunch I have is that on your platform, perhaps the `string()` accessor is not returning the plain string, but e.g. the quoted path. That would break the search. Consider using the `native()` accessor instead.

*(In fact, since `file_name` is NOT a path, but a string pattern, suggest [passing the argument as `std::string__view` or similar instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c93047d03a9da112).)*

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26dc76e4c38c77a7)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

template <typename Out>
void find_file(const fs::path& dir_path, const fs::path file_name, Out out) {
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dir_path), end;
    std::copy_if(it, end, out, [file_name](fs::path e) {
        return boost::algorithm::icontains(e.filename().native(),
                                           file_name.native());
    });
}

int main() {
    fs::path d = "a/b/c/e";
    fs::create_directories(d);
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(d / "1200E9408000EC0.jpeg");
    }

    std::cout << fs::path("000EC0").native() << "\n";

    std::vector<fs::path> found;
    find_file(".", "000EC0", back_inserter(found));

    for (auto &f : found)
    {
        std::cout << "Found: " << f << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
000EC0
Found: "./a/b/c/e/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg"
```

### UPDATE: Code Review

To the updated question, came up with an somewhat improved tester that works with `boost::filesystem` and with `std::filesystem` just the same.

There are many small improvements (removing repetition, explicit conversions, using optional to return optional matches, etc.

Also added a whitespace `trim` to avoid choking on extraneous whitespace on the input lines:

- **[Live On Coliru (`-DUSE_BOOST_FS`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c01fa06113869749)**
- **[Live On Coliru (std library)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/410b12e3874c698d)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using boost::algorithm::icontains;
using boost::algorithm::trim;

#if defined(USE_BOOST_FS)
    #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    using boost::system::error_code;
#else
    #include <filesystem>
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    using std::error_code;
#endif

void getfiles(
    const fs::path& root, const std::string& ext, std::vector<fs::path>& ret)
{
    if (!exists(root) || !is_directory(root))
        return;

    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root), endit; it != endit; ++it) {
        if (is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
            ret.push_back(it->path()); //
    }
}

std::optional<fs::path> find_file(const fs::path& dir_path, fs::path partial)
{
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator end,
        it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir_path);

    it = std::find_if(it, end, [partial](fs::path e) {
        auto search = partial.native();
        //std::cerr << e.filename().native() << "||" << search << std::endl;
        auto matches = icontains(e.filename().native(), search);
        std::cerr << e << " Matches: " << std::boolalpha << matches
                  << std::endl;
        return matches;
    });

    return (it != end)
        ? std::make_optional(it->path())
        : std::nullopt;
}

auto readInputClass(fs::path const& textFiles)
{
    std::vector<fs::path> found;
    getfiles(textFiles, ".txt", found);
    return found;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);
    auto const textFiles = readInputClass(args.at(1));
    std::string const datasetPath = args.at(2);

    for (fs::path classname : textFiles) {
        // open the text file
        std::ifstream lblFile(classname);

        // use base without extension as output directory
        classname.replace_extension();
        if (!fs::exists(classname)) {
            if (fs::create_directories(classname))
                std::cerr << classname << " created" << std::endl;
        }

        for (std::string line; getline(lblFile, line);) {
            trim(line);

            if (auto found = find_file(datasetPath, line)) {
                auto dest = classname / found->filename();

                error_code ec;
                copy(*found, dest, ec);
                std::cerr << dest << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Not Found \n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Testing from scratch with

```
mkdir -pv textfiles dataset
touch dataset/{vfv343434,fsdfdsfdfsf,1200E9408000EC0}.jpeg
echo 'E9408000EC0 ' > textfiles/490.txt
```

Running

```
./a.out textfiles/ dataset/
```

Prints

```
"textfiles/490" created
"dataset/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" Matches: true
"textfiles/490/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" (Success)
```

Or on subsequent run

```
"dataset/fsdfdsfdfsf.jpeg" Matches: false
"dataset/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" Matches: true
"textfiles/490/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" (File exists)
```

### BONUS

Doing some more diagnostics and avoiding repeatedly traversing the filesystem for each pattern. The main program is now:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55a08c9f7f064f60)**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);

    Paths const classes = getfiles(args.at(1), ".txt");
    Mappings map = readClassMappings(classes);

    std::cout << "Procesing " << map.size() << " patterns from "
              << classes.size() << " classes" << std::endl;

    processDatasetDir(args.at(2), map);
}
```

And the remaining functions are implemented as:

```
// be smart about case insenstiive patterns
struct Pattern : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
    using std::string::operator=;

#ifdef __cpp_lib_three_way_comparison
    std::weak_ordering operator<=>(Pattern const& other) const {
        if (boost::ilexicographical_compare(*this, other)) {
            return std::weak_ordering::less;
        } else if (boost::ilexicographical_compare(other, *this)) {
            return std::weak_ordering::less;
        }
        return std::weak_ordering::equivalent;
    }
#else
    bool operator<(Pattern const& other) const {
        return boost::ilexicographical_compare(*this, other);
    }
#endif
};

using Paths    = std::vector<fs::path>;
using Mapping  = std::pair<Pattern, fs::path>;
using Patterns = std::set<Pattern>;
using Mappings = std::set<Mapping>;

Mappings readClassMappings(Paths const& classes)
{
    Mappings mappings;
    for (fs::path classname : classes) {
        std::ifstream lblFile(classname);
        classname.replace_extension();

        for (Pattern pattern; getline(lblFile, pattern);) {
            trim(pattern);
            if (auto [it, ok] = mappings.emplace(pattern, classname); !ok) {
                std::cerr << "WARNING: " << std::quoted(pattern)
                          << " duplicates " << std::quoted(it->first)
                          << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return mappings;
}

size_t processDatasetDir(const fs::path& datasetPath, Mappings const& patterns)
{
    size_t copied = 0, failed = 0;
    Patterns found;

    using It = fs::recursive_directory_iterator;
    for (It it = It(datasetPath), end; it != end; ++it) {
        if (!it->is_regular_file())
            continue;

        fs::path const& entry = *it;

        for (auto& [pattern, location]: patterns) {
            if (icontains(it->path().filename().native(), pattern)) {
                found.emplace(pattern);

                if (!exists(location) && fs::create_directories(location))
                    std::cerr << location << " created" << std::endl;

                auto dest = location / entry.filename();

                error_code ec;
                copy(entry, dest, ec);
                std::cerr << dest << " (" << ec.message() << ") from "
                          << std::quoted(pattern) << "\n";

                (ec? failed : copied) += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Copied:" << copied
              << ", missing:" << patterns.size() - found.size()
              << ", failed: " << failed << std::endl;
    return copied;
}
```

With some more "random" test data:

```
mkdir -pv textfiles dataset
touch dataset/{vfv343434,fsdfdsfdfsf,1200E9408000EC0}.jpeg
echo .jPeg > textfiles/all_of_them.txt
echo $'E9408000EC0 \n e9408000ec0\nE9408\nbOgUs' > textfiles/490.txt
```

Running as

```
./a.out textfiles/ dataset/
```

Prints:

```
WARNING: "e9408000ec0" duplicates "E9408000EC0"
Procesing 4 patterns from 2 classes
"textfiles/all_of_them" created
"textfiles/all_of_them/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" (Success) from ".jPeg"
"textfiles/490" created
"textfiles/490/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" (Success) from "E9408"
"textfiles/490/1200E9408000EC0.jpeg" (File exists) from "E9408000EC0"
"textfiles/all_of_them/vfv343434.jpeg" (Success) from ".jPeg"
"textfiles/all_of_them/fsdfdsfdfsf.jpeg" (Success) from ".jPeg"
Copied:4, missing:1, failed: 1
```

Comment: For completeness, the same [working with std::filesystem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce3b2e19d7eae9d0) unodified

Comment: Thanks for both examples.

Comment: @sehe I tried what you have proposed  (adding .native()) still no luck :| I've also edited my question and added all the functions I'm using, maybe it gives you a better perspective, I'm struggling two days  with this peace of code and its driving me crazy I know there is something wrong but I cant find it

Comment: Still cannot repro [using boost](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c01fa06113869749) or [using std](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/410b12e3874c698d). I agree, it's **bound** to be the content of `line`. In fact, I added a trim just in case there's leaing/trailing whitespace on the input lines of the label files.

Comment: For fun, here's a version further refactored to do more diagnostics and only ever traverse the file-system once: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c3d2d0927b16c8d

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and detailed explanation everything is working fine and the problem solved !

Comment: @Amir Did you find out what caused it? Was it the whitespace `trim`?

Comment: @sehe actually I just copied your code and modify it so that I can use it with c++11,I started it on my server for organizing images from dataset, tomorrow morning I'll deeply investigate the codes and tell you what was causing the problem , but my guess is preprocessing the input  solved the problem !